# Why doesn't my `inline-block` work?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out why my `#logo` doesn't behave as it should, having `display: inline-block;`, `#logo` and `#main_nav` should be on the same line, however it doesn't.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

---

```css
#logo {
 margin: 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 350px;
 width: 350px;
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url("http://www.jeffarries.com/media/pictures/logos/jeff_cursive.png");
 display: inline-block;
}




ul, li {
 display: block !important;
}

li, ul {
 display: inline-block;
}

#main_nav {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
}

.nav_button:link {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 position: relative;
 color: black;
}

.nav_button:visited {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="/"><div id="logo"></div></a>



<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div id="main_nav" class="overlay-content">
   <a class="nav_button" href="/">Home</a>
   <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Blog</a>
   <a class="nav_button" href="">Trips</a> -->
   <a class="nav_button" href="/politics">Politics</a>
   <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Pictures</a> -->
   <a class="nav_button" href="/videos">Videos</a></li>
   <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Computer</a></li> -->
  </div> <!-- close main_nav -->
 </div> <!-- close myNav-->
```

Comment: For starters your HTML is invalid

Comment: @j08691 What is invalid?

Comment: The errant `</li>`

Comment: @j08691 THANKS! I didn't see that!

Comment: Are you not validating your markup with the validator?

Comment: @Rob What validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width to your nav container and align the text to center. The `inline-block` depends on the space, it will move to second line if there is not enough space.

```css
#logo {
  margin: 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://www.jeffarries.com/media/pictures/logos/jeff_cursive.png");
  display: inline-block;
}
ul,
li {
  display: block !important;
}
li,
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
#myNav {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#main_nav {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.nav_button:link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}
.nav_button:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">
  <div id="logo"></div>
</a>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div id="main_nav" class="overlay-content">
    <a class="nav_button" href="/">Home</a>
    <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Blog</a>
   <a class="nav_button" href="">Trips</a> -->
    <a class="nav_button" href="/politics">Politics</a>
    <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Pictures</a> -->
    <a class="nav_button" href="/videos">Videos</a>
    <!-- <a class="nav_button" href="">Computer</a></li> -->
  </div>
  <!-- close main_nav -->
<!-- close myNav-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, this breaks my `float`.

Comment: Yes, for me it does.

Comment: Yes, I realized once I posted that that is was to the right, but I'm still having the original issue with the `inline-block`.

Comment: Why did you delete all your comments, did I offend you in some way?

Comment: Also, take a look at my website, http://jeffarries.com, for me at least, sometimes it displays as I want it to (with `inline-block` working) and other times it displays as I don't want it to (with `inline-block` not working), isn't that weird?

Comment: @JeffArries I am sorry, I couldn't understand your problem. And usually we remove comments when they are more. It doesn't mean I am offended. Best of luck for your project.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I'm glad I didn't offend you.  Thanks for your wishes and trying to help me as much as you could!

Answer (score 2):

Your parent `#myNav` doesn't have apply any style, so the browser default would set the `display` to `block`. Hence make it wrap to another line. Make it `inline-block` to fix the problem.

```css
    #logo {
     margin: 5px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 350px;
     width: 350px;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url("http://www.jeffarries.com/media/pictures/logos/jeff_cursive.png");
     display: inline-block;
    }

    ul {
     display: block;
    }
    li, #myNav {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #main_nav {
     float: right;
     margin: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav_button:link {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: inline-block;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 2px;
     position: relative;
     color: black;
    }

    .nav_button:visited {
     color: black;
    }
```

```html
<a href="/"><div id="logo"></div></a>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div id="main_nav" class="overlay-content">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="nav_button" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_button" href="/politics">Politics</a></li></ul>
  </div> <!-- close main_nav -->
 </div> <!-- close myNav-->
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  However, it breaks my `float` and the nav bar still doesn't totally go to the top, which it should (almost).

Comment: There are several problems to fix, I just point out the the most obvious one I saw lol. If you only need the nav to go to the top of the page, simply add `float: right` to your `#myNav` too. There are better practices to make a navbar, I recommend to check how the famous ones (bootstrap, foundation etc) did it.